# Crouching animation doesn't go as I planned, I think it's a syntax error somewhere but I can't really find it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem I have is this: when I crouch idle and not moving, it's triggering the animation of idleCrouch, but when I start walking while I'm crouching, it's not transitioning to the isCrouchWalk animation as it should. By the way the animator on unity is setup perfectly it's just a code problem as far as I'm aware, *Note - when im walking and then pressing on C to crouch it is triggering the CrouchWalk animation, only if i try to transition from crouch idle to crouch walk its stuck on the crouch idle animation

This is the code:

```
void Movement()
{
    isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

    if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
    {
        velocity.y = -2f;
    }

    float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;
    velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("isJumping");
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
    }

    if (WeaponHolster.selectedWep == 0 || WeaponHolster.selectedWep == 1||WeaponHolster.selectedWep==2)
    {
        if (direction.magnitude > 0.1f)
        {
            animator.SetBool("WalkForward", true);

            float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
            float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);
            Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
            controller.Move(moveDir.normalized * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else  if (isCrouching && direction.magnitude >0.1f)
        {
            animator.SetBool("isCrouchWalk", true);
        }
        else if (direction.magnitude ==0f&&isCrouching)
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsIdleCrouch", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("WalkForward", false);
            animator.SetBool("IsIdleCrouch", false);
        }
    }

    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}

void Crouching()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C) && !ShotgunEngine.isReloading)
    {
        animator.SetBool("isCrouchWalk", true);

        isCrouching = true;
        aiming.m_Offset = new Vector3(0.4f, 0f, 1);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.C))
    {
        animator.SetBool("isCrouchWalk", false);
        isCrouching = false;
        aiming.m_Offset = new Vector3(0.4f, 0.2f, 0);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I noticed that all of your bool names start capitalized, except the one is question.  Maybe it should be `"IsCrouchWalk"`?

Comment: no no i actualy checked this its all written the correct way by the way , if i chagne all of those "else if " to if's its doing the opposite the WalkForward animation not triggering i think its the syntax

Comment: If it was a syntax error then you would not be able to press play.  A syntax error is caught at compile time and appears as a red error in the unity console.  This seems like a logic error.

Comment: Sorry, i meant it was a syntax problem like its not written correctly or in the right order , english is not my native language so sorry in advance

Comment: No problem.  In general syntax refers to how the language is written, ie. needing a semi-colon at the end of statement in c#.  We may need some more debugging information.  If you can include a screen shot of the animation transitions, that would be helpful.

Comment: https://ibb.co/WVv24hF , i didnt screenshoted the whole screen cuz its just a mess over there still learning , the two lines between idle to walk is the boolean parameter iscrouchidle false and true

Answer (score 2):

The issue is most likely the condition.  If you look at the first `if` statement it is:

```
if (direction.magnitude > 0.1f)
```

Then you have the `else if` which is

```
else if (isCrouching && direction.magnitude > 0.1f)
```

The else can never be true, because if the first `if` is not true, that means the `direction.magnitude` is equal or less than `0.1f`.

You could try moving the condition to inside of the first condition block.

```
if (direction.magnitude > 0.1f)
{
    if (isCrouching)
    {
        animator.SetBool("isCrouchWalk", true);
    }
    else
    {
        animator.SetBool("WalkForward", true);

        float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
        float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);
        Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
        controller.Move(moveDir.normalized * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }       
}
```

Comment: i understand what u saying yea , but i tried using what u gave me it didnt actually worked kinda messed up the walking directions and didnt trigger the crouch walk as well

Comment: Agree with @hijinxbassist here, their logic is sound. Look at your code again.

Comment: You might need to set the other bools to false.  Try adding `animator.SetBool("WalkForward", false);`, and whichever other bools might be affecting the transitions.  I am really only guessing here, adding a screenshot of the animation window with the transitions would be helpful.

Comment: ibb.co/WVv24hF , i didnt screenshoted the whole screen cuz its just a mess over there still learning , the two lines between idle to walk is the boolean parameter iscrouchidle false and true

Comment: mos probably also will want to extract the code for moving from that check at all but rather apply certain modifiers etc ...I assume you would want your character to be moving in both states just slower when crouching

Comment: No, so the problem here is when i go crouching(idle) its fine but when i start walking while im crouching the crouch idle wont set to false and set the crouch walking to true